# Using PHP/MYSQL to sort data based on partial values

Tags: php, mysql

I got prefix values setup for my products that help me identify drinks from food. If its a drink it will contain `(D)` as the prefix.

```
(D)Beer
Burger
(D)Soft Drink
Sandwich

SELECT * FROM orders  order by pname
```

I want to sort the drinks together and the food together in a single query.   Hope that makes sence and thx for the help :)

Comment: you could substr (D) in the query.

Comment: Can you provide your table definition?

Comment: Why do you put use a prefix to distinguish drinks from food? Why don't you use another column in the table, call is `is_drink`?

Comment: @Austin and I seem to have interpreted your question differently. Could you show the results you want to get?

Comment: Hungarian notation in relational data. Awful.

Comment: Thanks for the support guys. I want the results to show like this:

(D)Beer<br>
(D)Soft Drink<br>
Burger<br>
Sandwich

Comment: @quatchis OK, then you will want to use Barmar's answer

Comment: Ok so I have 1 more problem. I need it to order by ID first and then by the prefix. Any ideas how can I add that to the query?

Comment: If you order by ID first, then nothing else matters. Multiple ordering criteria only matters when there are duplicates in the earlier criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
ORDER BY LEFT(pname, 3) = "(D)", pname
```

`LEFT(pname, 3) = "(D)"` will be `0` for drinks, `1` for foods. So this will put all drinks first, then all foods. So the results will be:

```
(D)Beer
(D)Soft Drink
Burger
Sandwich
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query, will work..

***select * from orders order by case

when pname LIKE "(D)%" then 1

else 2

end***